# Unbind click event in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an ul li list which is dynamically generated. I want to bind a click event on the click of a list element. Since I'm using jquery 1.44 I make use of live():

```
$(function(){

    $('ul li').live('click', function(){
        alert('click');
    });

    $('ul').delegate('click', 'li', function(){
        alert('click');
    });

});
```

Neither of those methods are working, and I believe it's because the [Ajax control toolkit autocomplete](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) creates a native click method which interferes with my jquery methods. I've also tried adding `unbind('click')` before binding my click events, without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried looking in the chrome devTools or firebug to see what is actually bound?

Comment: @ben336 I don't think they can show the actual event. And even if they did, I've tried all of jQuerys methods to unbind them, without success.

Comment: in Chrome devtools under elements you can click on an element and the bottom left will show you what event listeners are bound to the event.  That will at least tell you whether your click listeners are being bound and what the ASP.net stuff is binding on there as well.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using jQuery 1.44, use [`.die()`](http://api.jquery.com/die/) to remove the bound event.

```
$('ul li').die('click');
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this somewhere public?

Comment: I'm afraid not... Need an asp.net site with ajax control toolkit autocomplete

Comment: Does the comment in this thread (http://forums.asp.net/t/1619091.aspx) possibly apply to your situation?

Comment: No, its about UpdatePanels. My question is about the autocomplete part. Thanks though.

Comment: Well that's why I said possibly apply. I know it's not the same control, but the comment about "because an update panel replaces all the html inside of itelf on an async postback, all the jQuery objects created in the panel must be recreated when the postback completes." sounded like it might point you in the right direction.